# How can I fill xamarin forms gridview data from database with horizontal scrolling

Tags: mysql, listview, xamarin, gridview, scroll

Whenever I load Data from mysql database (remotely), it loads fine but the 20 columns can't fit on potrait view. It tends to push the extra columns to new row, making the gridview disorganized.

How can I make the whole 20 columns appear on one horizontal row with a scrolling feature (horizontal)
All the related properties in xaml seam irresponsive. Thanks.

Comment: use ColletionView - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/collectionview/

Answer (score 0):

You can do this if you add the `Grid` inside `ScrollView` and set the `Orientation` property to `Horizontal`

Like this

```
<ContentPage.Content>
    <ScrollView Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalOptions="Center">
        <Grid VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">

            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

            <Button Grid.Column="0" Text="Button1" BackgroundColor="MediumSeaGreen" />
            <Button Grid.Column="1" Text="Button2" />
            <Button Grid.Column="2" Text="Button3" BackgroundColor="DodgerBlue" />
            <Button Grid.Column="3" Text="Button4" />
            <Button Grid.Column="4" Text="Button5" BackgroundColor="CadetBlue" />

        </Grid>
    </ScrollView>
</ContentPage.Content>
```

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lkgCt.gif)

Comment: But these properties don't seam to exist in xamarin forms (visual studio). Are they for Android studio?  Because I'm using visual studio  only.

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:p1="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    p1:minWidth="25px"
    p1:minHeight="25px"
    p1:layout_width="match_parent"
    p1:layout_height="match_parent"
    p1:id="@+id/scrollView1">
    <GridView
        p1:minWidth="25px"
        p1:minHeight="25px"
        p1:layout_width="match_parent"
        p1:layout_height="match_parent"
        p1:id="@+id/gridView1" />
</ScrollView>

Comment: @Robertseyaro Anas Alweish's codes are used in Xamarin.Forms,and your codes above is used in Xamarin.Android or native Android (Android Studio).

Comment: It can't be Android studio because I copied it from visual studio 2015 Enterprise, my own project.

Comment: @Robertseyaror so your project is Xamarin.Android ?